# AngularJS $scope updating in javascript but not in the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, dom

I am making a request from the server and getting a correct response. That array of objects is `$scope.photos`. To add a photo, I make a request get the data back and then I've tried two things but both don't update the $scope in the HTML, while they do - in the script.

1. I've tried sending an $http request then sends back the whole array of photos, i added them in the javascript `$scope.images` array. They were added when I console.logged them but `$scope.images` didn't update in the HTML.
2. I've tried sending the same thing and just adding it to `$scope.images` using `$scope.images.push(...)`, but still it doesn't work. I get no error.

Here's the code where I declare `$scope.images`:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/photos'
}).then(function(data){
    $scope.images = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(data.data));
});
```

Everything here works properly. Here, I'm sending the request and receiving the data. I get the expected array.

```
var data = {
  title: $scope.newImage.title,
  url: $scope.newImage.url
} 

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/add',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: data
  }).then(function(response, callback){
    var newPhoto = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(response.data));
    $scope.images.push({
      title: newPhoto.title,
      url: newPhoto.url
    });
    console.log($scope.images); // the newImage is logged as well
  })
 }
```

The `newImage` is logged as well, `$scope.images` is getting updated in the script. But there's no difference in the html. Here's the html btw

```
<div class="gallery-item" ng-repeat="image in images | orderBy: 
  'created_at':true | filter: search">
    <img ng-src="{{ image.url }}" class="gallery-item--image" ng- 
  click="selectedImage = image;openImage($event)" />
    <span class="gallery-item--label">{{ image.title }}</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: refer article http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html for better approach to update bindings.

Comment: If you remove the `orderBy` and `filter` pipes in the `ng-repeat`, do the new images appear?

Comment: No, if i remove them , it still doesn't work

Comment: is your gallery inside a ng-if?

Comment: No, it's not, it's a straightaway ng-repeat. Also, Everything else in the app works fine

Answer (score 1):

I remember encounter similar problem before, I don't know my solution can work, but no harm for you to give it a try.
The first thing I try is to renew the reference to the images array

```
$scope.images = $scope.images.slice();
```

This could renew the reference to the images array therefor angular able to detect the change happen with the images array

And I always do the `trackBy` could be `id` or `index`, this could help angular improve the `ng-repeat` significantly in template.

Comment: can you give the code for using this `trackby` `index` or something? Nothing seems to work right now

Comment: you could find it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates